# How can I encrypt a license key in .Net source code?

Tags: .net, encryption

We have an application that uses paid third party components. How can I encrypt the license key for these components so that other developers cannot get this key?

Assuming some code like this:

```
AnyComponent.LicenseKey = "abcd1234";
```

I could encrypt the key and put it in the App Config or Web Config, but if the application needs to decrypt this at runtime, other developers would be able to as well by just adding a breakpoint.

What's the solution to this?

Comment: There is no (real) solution to that. If the application needs the value at runtime, then by definition, any user executing the application is able to read the value from the application's memory as well. The best you can hope for is to make it as complicated and unattractive as possible to do that, but with managed code this is no small feat -- for starters, `AnyComponent.LicenseKey` is presumably a public property of `string` type, and .NET's reflection features make it particularly simple to find. A bit of managed debugging will easily get you the value at runtime.

Comment: One approach is to minimize information available on-site and use online services as much as possible (since you control those) and to use license keys that aren't valid in perpetuity so you can expire them. Ultimately, though, non-technical solutions where you lay down in your license agreements what is and isn't allowed and then let the lawyers sort it out is more realistic from a business perspective.

Comment: Online services is a good approach - Load all keys from an online service when starting and only on production. Was hoping for a simpler solution. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Dispite @JeroenMostert afirmations are 100% correct, I would start by doing a class  using "TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider" and, assuming I can, I would create a dll with this class:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace MyProject.CryptServices
{
    public sealed class Crypt
    {
        private TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TripleDes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

        /// <summary>
        /// truncate hash
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key"></param>
        /// <param name="length"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private byte[] TruncateHash(string key, int length)
        {
            var sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();

            // Hash the key.
            var keyBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(key);
            var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(keyBytes);

            // Truncate or pad the hash.
            Array.Resize(ref hash, length);
            return hash;
        }

        public Crypt()
        {
            string key = "..321MyVeryComplicated@KeyForThisProject123..";
            // Initialize the crypto provider.
            TripleDes.Key = TruncateHash(key, TripleDes.KeySize / 8);
            TripleDes.IV = TruncateHash("", TripleDes.BlockSize / 8);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// encrypt
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="plaintext"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string EncryptData(string plaintext)
        {

            // Convert the plaintext string to a byte array.
            var plaintextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plaintext);

            // Create the stream.
            var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            // Create the encoder to write to the stream.
            var encStream = new CryptoStream(ms, TripleDes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            // Use the crypto stream to write the byte array to the stream.
            encStream.Write(plaintextBytes, 0, plaintextBytes.Length);
            encStream.FlushFinalBlock();

            // Convert the encrypted stream to a printable string.
            return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// decrypt
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="encryptedtext"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string DecryptData(string encryptedtext)
        {
            string res = "";
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(encryptedtext))
                goto nullText;
            // Convert the encrypted text string to a byte array.
            var encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedtext);

            // Create the stream.
            var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            // Create the decoder to write to the stream.
            var decStream = new CryptoStream(ms, TripleDes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            // Use the crypto stream to write the byte array to the stream.
            decStream.Write(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length);
            decStream.FlushFinalBlock();

            // Convert the plaintext stream to a string.
            res = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        nullText:
            ;
            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, on my project, I reference this dll (not the project/class) and encrypt/decrypt data when needed.

Comment: We already have something similar. But how would this stop a developer from getting the license key at the point where it is returned from the DLL ?

Comment: Complete waste of time, there is nothing to stop someone with a debugger bypassing this. Also missing `using` blocks everywhere

Comment: This would simply seem to shift the burden to protecting the key used for encryption, which is not simpler than protecting the license key. At best such encryption can be used to minimize the number of discrete pieces of information that need to be protected, but it won't solve the central problem. Rather than custom encryption code I'd suggest using DPAPI instead (`ProtectedData`), which is simpler and can at least additionally restrict access to the current user/machine only, with the only drawback being that it's not portable (Windows only).